# How to make BroadcastReceiver not restart when the app is closed and started?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to have an app that creates a task that runs every 2 hours when the app is started, but when I close the app and open it again my onReceive gets called.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 2*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

As you can see, the third argument to `alarmManager.setRepeating` is `System.currentTimeMillies()` which means that the BroadcastReceiver will be called immediately, and then every 2 hours. But if I open the app, close it by sliding it to the side and start it up again then BroadcastReceiver gets notified before two hours have passed and I don't want this to happen. How can I prevent this from happening?
Here's my AlarmReciever.java:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Random rng = new Random();
    boolean isRegistered = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(isRegistered)
            return;
        isRegistered = true;
        List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "foods.txt");
        if(!file.exists())
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("foods.txt");
            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    foods.add(new Food(line.split("\\|")[0], Boolean.valueOf(line.split("\\|")[1])));
                }
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Food> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Food food : foods) {
            if(food.isAvailable())
                temp.add(food);
        }
        Food food = temp.get(rng.nextInt(temp.size()));

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Food Reminder!")
                .setContentText("Remember you still have " + food.getText().trim() + " in your home!")
                .setSound(soundUri);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

How can I prevent this from happening and just always have it running every 2 hours unless the app is forced stop or I code it via code?

Also: I'm using the `isRegistered` variable to prevent the app from creating multiple AlarmRecivers when I close and open the app, is this how I should do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is if you're killing your Activity all variables will be crushed. That means you have to do this kind of thing in the BroadcastReceiver itself.

you could define a new Variable in your `AlarmReceiver` class:
`private Long LastTime = 0;`
then you put this

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(isRegistered)
        return;
    if((System.currentTimeMillis()-LastTime)<7200000 && !intent.getBooleanExtra("ignoreTime",false))
        return;
    LastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    isRegistered = true;
    List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "foods.txt");
    if(!file.exists())
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("foods.txt");
        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                foods.add(new Food(line.split("\\|")[0], Boolean.valueOf(line.split("\\|")[1])));
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<Food> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Food food : foods) {
        if(food.isAvailable())
            temp.add(food);
    }
    Food food = temp.get(rng.nextInt(temp.size()));

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Food Reminder!")
            .setContentText("Remember you still have " + food.getText().trim() + " in your home!")
            .setSound(soundUri);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

now if you want to ignore the timer (cause I assume sometimes you dont wanna wait 2 hours) you have to modify the intent you use to trigger the broadcast receiver like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setBooleanExtra("ignoreTime",true);
```

WHY YOU CANT DO THIS WITHIN THE MAIN CLASS:
the Problem is if your Activity dies all scheduled Intents, variables etc die because you did literally destroy it. to do this from your activity you would have to do something in the `onDestroy()` method that saves some variable to the storage i.E. `SharedPreferences` which holds the last time the receiver was called. If for some reason however your activity would get TERMINATED you wouldnt call onDestroy so even that Method is pretty risky

Comment: I have no idea why but this is not working for me, it will still run the task again when I restart the app. As a different approach I tried making <code>boolean isRegisted</code> static and check in MainActivity.java if its set to true and if not run the code that starts it, but this doesn't work either. Does it not keep track of variables inside AlarmReciever.java?

Comment: I tried something that seems to work and its creating a file after I run the code to start the alarm and only if it doesn't exist run that code. Is this good practice?

Comment: I just realized that creating a file means that if the app is force stopped I can't delete it and therefore when the app is opened again it won't start the timer. Why did the variable solution not work for me?

Comment: So my approach now is to check in MainActivity.java if AlarmReciever.isRegistered (now static) is false and then run the alarm manager, but this only work after the onRecieve was called once when the app is stopped for some reason